# how to style react big calendar border

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-big-calendar, css-in-js

im working with react big calendar , and i how done some style with it , but i need to remove the border around the color of the `month-view` , i want to remove the border that wrap the calendar and wrap each column and row .

this the how its look :
[image]

this the code :

```
div>
      <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        events={events}
        views={['month']}
        onNavigate={onNavigate}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        style={{ height: '600px', width: '100%' }}
        components={{
          header: CalendarHeaderStyled,
          toolbar: CalendarToolbar,
        }}
        eventPropGetter={(event) => {


          if (event...) {
            return {
              style: {
               ...some style
              },
            };
          } else {
            return {
              style: {
                ...some style
              },
            };
          }
        }}
        dayPropGetter={(date) => {
          ...some code;

          return {
            style: {
              ....some style,
            },
          };
        }}
        onSelectEvent={(event) => {
          .... some code);
        }}
      />
```

Comment: in [document](https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#intro) . Styles can be found at: react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css, and should be included on the page with the calendar component. Also make sure that your calendar's container element has a height, or the calendar won't be visible (see why below).

Comment: I have removed `typescript` tag and added `css-in-js`, `css` and `javascript`. Please consider sharing reproducible example. `...some style` is not valid code and it takes some time for people who want to answer your question to fix syntax errors. Try `also` add a link to any code sandbox but pls keep in mind that full reproducible code also should be pasted in your question